# Generating junit xml report from Android in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, junit, report

I know that this topic was discussed there a lot of times, but I've never found the step-by-step answer (if it exists).

1. I have Android project created with Eclipse with test project in 'tests' folder, like in official tutorials
2. I have some android junit test, I can see the results in Eclipse, but I need the xml report file to analyze it in Jenkins. I've found lib for creating reports, but it uploads the xml file onto emulator/device, I think a need it to be local (in my project folder). There is also Maven plugin that can do it, but I don't use Maven in my project (Android plugin for Eclipse uses ant I think).
3. Is there any way to modify build process and get this report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not pull the file that is generated in the emulator/device using "adb pull" command...you can add this as part of the ant script???

Example:

```
  <echo>Downloading file into project directory...</echo>
    <exec executable="${adb}" failonerror="true">
        <arg line="${adb.device.arg}" />
        <arg value="pull" />
        <arg value="/sdcard/junit.xml" />
        <arg value="junit.xml" />
    </exec>
```

Answer (score 0):

This [presentation](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2011/08/linuxcon-2011-north-america.html) covers the issue briefly, but you can follow the step by step example.
The [Android Application Testing Guide](http://www.packtpub.com/android-application-testing-guide/book) book covers it in more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the link! The presentation is very useful.